# C# "invalid providertype" with Google Service account

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

Im no expert in c# and this is my first project with the google api and a service account. Im running into a problem that i have no idea how to solve. This code works on 2 computers but doesnt on the 3rd.

The 3rd computer gives an error invalid prototype error when trying to run.
Checked code to [Documentation Google API - Service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account)

What could be the problem?

Used code:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };
var keyFilePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "www.site.nl-012345678.p12";
string serviceAccountEmail = "name@api-project-000000000000.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
string applicationName = "www.applicationname.nl";
string password = "notasecret";

//loading the Key file<br>
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{
    Scopes = scopes
}.FromCertificate(certificate));

// setup the service
var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = applicationName
});
```

Edit (Added stacktrace):

```
Serverfout in toepassing /.  
Ongeldig providertype opgegeven.
Beschrijving: Er is een onverwerkte uitzondering opgetreden tijdens het uitvoeren van de huidige webaanvraag. Raadpleeg de stacktracering voor meer informatie over deze fout en de oorsprong ervan in de code.

Details van uitzondering: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Ongeldig providertype opgegeven.


Fout in bron:


Regel 37:             var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
Regel 38:             var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
Regel 39:             {
Regel 40:                 Scopes = scopes
Regel 41:             }.FromCertificate(certificate));


Bronbestand: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\git\ttldashboard\ttldashboard\Helpers\GoogleAnalytics.cs    Regel: 39

Stacktracering:


[CryptographicException: Ongeldig providertype opgegeven.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer) +5265821
   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle) +94
   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair() +136
   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize) +203
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey() +240
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Initializer.FromCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate) in C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:115
   ttldashboard.Helpers.GoogleAnalytics.GetAnalyticsService() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\git\ttldashboard\ttldashboard\Helpers\GoogleAnalytics.cs:39
   ttldashboard.Helpers.GoogleAnalytics.GetGoogleExitClicks(Int32 locatieId, String startDate, String stopDate) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\git\ttldashboard\ttldashboard\Helpers\GoogleAnalytics.cs:146
   ttldashboard.Controllers.DashboardController.Index() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\git\ttldashboard\ttldashboard\Controllers\DashboardController.cs:67
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137


Versiegegevens: Microsoft .NET Framework Versie:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Versie:4.6.1038.0
```

Comment: Could you post more details about the exception (innerexception(s), stacktrace(s) etc.)?

Comment: We could use a little info on the machine that's not working. as @JevgeniGeurtsen we need to see the full exception its throwing.

Comment: Added the complete stacktrace, is this sufficiënt?

Comment: Any chance you feel like downloading the Service account Json file instead of the P12 file.   Then I can give you some different code to use?

Comment: Details of any differences between the machines that are working at the one that isn't would indeed be very useful.

Comment: Its not the normal azure error either.   that's normally a gateway or proxy server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a crypto issue with the certificate on that machine.   If I could recreate it I would probably play with it just to see what is causing it but since I cant here is a "possible" way around it.

Go to google developers console.  Download the service account .Json file instead of the service account .p12 file.   Then use this code instead

```
 GoogleCredential credential;
 using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       {
       credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(scopes);
       }

 // Create the service.
 var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Google Authentication Sample",
    });
```

If you really want to know what could be causing it I will see if I can find someone to ping.

Comment: Thanks switching to the json file fixed the problem!

Couldnt use AnalyticsReportingService() btw, had to use AnalyticsService() instead.

Comment: AnalyticsReportingService is Google Analytics v4  is AnalyticsService v3 sorry I should have looked at your code rather then just copying mine. I updated the answer with the correct service.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem (I use the P12 file).  The code worked on my desktop, but then failed with the "invalid providertype" error once I deployed it to Azure.

What I was missing was: X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet

Like this:

```
string sKeyFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Keys/" + ServiceAccountKey);
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sKeyFile))
{
    throw new Exception("Key file can't be found! " + sKeyFile);
}

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(sKeyFile, "notasecret", 
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```